# React - Preserve DOM Element When Not Rendered and Reuse Later

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, react-dom

I want to hide and show items in a page in response to user actions, but for efficiency I'm curious if it's possible to save the actual `HTMLElement`'s and make React reuse/reinsert them when the items are unhidden (but none of their render properties have changed). Assume those items are very taxing to render - for example, a large `img` whose server prohibits caching.

The naive approach would be:

```
{ this.props.showImage && <img src="very-large-non-cachable-image.png"/> }
```

where `showImage` would flip based on user input. The problem is that every time the image is hidden and re-shown, the browser has to download the image again (because the server prohibits caching).

Obviously I can use `ref` to get the `HTMLElement` for the `img`. But, is it possible to make React *reuse* that HTMLElement after the element is removed and subsequently re-rendered? In other words, to just re-insert the saved/cached `HTMLElement` back into the DOM?

P.S. - I realize the scenario I've set up is a little unusual and that an obvious alternative would be to use `display: none` rather than `false`ing out the entire `img`. But please assume for argument's sake that I want and need to do this the way I've described; my true scenario is too complex to fully describe here, but suffice it to say the items are taxing to re-render on each hide/show, but I also don't want them to actually be in the DOM (virtual or otherwise) when not visible (hence `display: none` is not an option).

Thanks!